# Maximum size of "TEXT" datatype in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I am working with python.

I have a field with  "text" datatype in postgres. Whenever I try to save a very large string, it throws internal error in python, but if I save the string with a smaller size, it saves it properly.

I don't understand the problem. Is it that there is some maximum limit for entering the characters for "TEXT" datatype?

Comment: What is the error ? are you sure you don't have any characters in the large text which might break the query , something like ' ?

Comment: Is there a constraint which is limiting the size of the column?

Comment: What is the error message concrete? How does the line look, which throws it?

Comment: my guess your problem is you're using varchar with fixed length underneath accidentally?

Answer (score 69):

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html):

> In any case, the longest possible character string that can be stored
>   is about 1 GB.

Comment: It saves the large string for the first time. but when tried saving again, by adding even 1 extra character, it gives "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR: TRANSACTIONS ABORTED UNTIL END OF THE BLOCK"

Comment: Check the logfiles to see all error messages, this looks like the last one, the one that doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: Is this 100% correct? From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) it also says:

**(The maximum value that will be allowed for n in the data type declaration is less than that. It wouldn't be useful to change this because with multibyte character encodings the number of characters and bytes can be quite different. If you desire to store long strings with no specific upper limit, use text or character varying without a length specifier, rather than making up an arbitrary length limit.)**

Comment: @Carlos - It seems that sentence says text may have different characters quantity (for encoding reasons) for same size (1GB in this case)