# Rails3: Validate text max length before storing in DB

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-postgresql

I'm currently using 'store' in my Rails model to persist various things in a hash. This is convenient as I don't have to create lots of individual attributes for this data, it serializes/de-serializes for me, and I can easily access each of the individual hash attributes as needed.  Code snippet (simplified):

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :data

  # Data is a nested hash
  store :data

  # Validation
  validates_presence_of :data
end
```

I realize this design may not be ideal when/if :data becomes very large (a whole other topic), but in the meantime, I would like to know the following:

1. What is the default max size of a 'text' column?  I'm using a PostGres DB currently, and I believe it is using VARCHAR behind the scenes, but not sure what the MAX size for this column actually is in the DB?
2. Can I explicitly set the max size for this :data text column in my Rails migration create_table code?
3. What will Rails do if I attempt to save a record where this :data attribute is too large?  Research leads me to believe it will chop it, and store what it can fit (very bad!)
4. How do I best protect against potential hash corruption and validate the :data size < MAX allowed size before storing in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

set a max length in your migration

http://databasically.com/2011/03/01/a-limit-of-rails-migrations/

then validate for the length in your model

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#length

Comment: Thanks, that answers #2, and easy to implement for #4.

Comment: However, I'm still curious if anyone knows what Rails is creating via migrations in PostGres (actual PG SQL) for a 'text' type and what the default MAX size is?

Comment: Regarding #3, with the validation in place, this will never be an issue. However, I believe that if your data length exceeds your max length, it will throw an error, maybe? Why not just try and see?

Comment: Yes, I verified the validation error when I explicitly set the limit to something small. However, I haven't had time to build a proper test that auto generates something really large to see what the default MAX size is (when I don't set a limit).  My guess is the default MAX is pretty big...

Comment: There is an answer to #1 recorded on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395975/maximum-size-of-text-datatype-in-postgresql

To wit, the maximum length that can be stored is 1 GB